# Перенос строки в конце на python

Tags: python

Как реализовать функцию чтобы с заданным лимитом в 38 символов суммировано ставить перенос строки. Например ввод (без переносов строки):

> Равным образом сложившаяся структура организации играет важную роль в формировании форм воздействия. Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что выбранный нами инновационный путь играет важную роль в формировании экономической целесообразности принимаемых решений. Задача организации, в особенности же выбранный нами инновационный путь напрямую зависит от системы масштабного изменения ряда параметров.

И вывод:

```
Равным образом сложившаяся структура
организации играет важную роль в
формировании форм воздействия.
Значимость этих проблем настолько
очевидна, что выбранный нами
инновационный путь играет важную
роль в формировании экономической
целесообразности принимаемых решений.
Задача организации, в особенности же
выбранный нами инновационный путь
напрямую зависит от системы
масштабного изменения ряда параметров.
```

Мои старания безполезны

```
def message_enter(message, width):
    word_list = message.split()
    i = 0
    text = ''
    while i < len(word_list):
       i += 1
       if len(word_list[i]) + len(word_list[i+1]) < width:
           text = text.join(f'{word_list[i]} {word_list[i+1]}')
       if len(word_list[i]) + len(word_list[i+1]) == width:
           text = text.join(f'{word_list[i]} {word_list[i+1]}\n')
       if len(word_list[i]) + len(word_list[i+1]) > width:
           text = text.join(f'{word_list[i]}\n{word_list[i+1]}')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16430216/7485582

Comment: Спасибо вам, ваш комментарий очень полезен и важен для меня)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html).

```
textwrap.fill(message, width)
```

Посмотрите реализацию этого метода. Вначале вызывается [_split_chunks](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8e2c0fd7ada79107f7e0d9c465e77fb36a9486e5/Lib/textwrap.py#L336), которая разделяет исходную строку по пробелам, потом действует [_wrap_chunks](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8e2c0fd7ada79107f7e0d9c465e77fb36a9486e5/Lib/textwrap.py#L233).

Comment: Спасибо тебе, добрый человек)